# Open PDF from Chrome IFRAME failed with default PDF viewer

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, pdf-viewer

The code looks like:

```html
    <iframe pm-attr-iframe class="widget-body" ng-src="{{vm.iframeUrl}}"  sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-forms allow-top-navigation">
    (not available)
</iframe>
```

Click the PDF link inside the iframe, it opens with white content.
If right click the mouse and click "Save", it works.

If open the URL to any tab or window, the PDF file rendered with default PDF viewer.

If I add other PDF viewer to Chrome extensions, it always works.

Is it caused by default PDF viewer of Chrome? How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the sandbox make the iframe lost permission to access the PDF file on Chrome, but all other web browsers do not have this behaviour.

After remove `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-forms allow-scripts"`, it works.

```
<iframe pm-attr-iframe class="widget-body" ng-src="{{vm.iframeUrl}}">
    (not available)
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found another way to fix this.
If your site needs to stick with `sandbox` for some reason, you can add the value `allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox` to fix this issue.

Comment: Here is a more complete set of settings that open up the iframe sandbox: sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use 'embed' or 'object' for embedding pdf in your web page as iframe with sandbox attribute blocks loading of pdfs unless you append 'https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=' to the URL.