# PDF redirection shows blank on Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf, redirect

I'm having this issue that I can't solve for the life of me.

I have a simple php script that redirects to pdfs, the code is as follows:

```
$file = "url/to/file";    
header("Pragma: public");

header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="somefile.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

readfile($file);
exit();
```

If I try it directly in a browser tab, it works, it connects with Chrome's pdf plugin and shows it to me. If I try to put this on a link on another page, or try to open it via window.open in javascript, It shows a blank page. This only happens in Chrome and Safari, Firefox and Edge show it fine. Before anyone asks, I've tried it with and without the cache and content-description headers, which I've got from answers I found here, this is just the last version I have.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

I forgot to mention that the problem persists on the blank tab even if I reload the page. I've checked the Network tab on devtools, they show identical results for bot requests and responses (the redirect and the direct one) but the redirect doesn't work. Also, no errors of any kind on either one.

Also, I've tried it without the exit(), doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Isn;t there something else that you need to do? You are reading the file into memory then exiting the code.

Comment: @jeff php `readfile` reads and outputs : http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php `Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer`

Comment: @KarlReid well there ya go - learn something new every day :-) (Note to self - check manual before opening big mouth).

Comment: Could you check the devtools and see if there is any error, or what the request/response looks like in the Network tab?

Comment: @jeff I also tried it without the exit(), no dice.

Comment: @KarlReid, I've done that, the devtool show the exact same request, I didn't mention that the problem persists even if you refresh the tab that the link redirected to, I'll edit the question

Comment: Does it work in older Chrome versions? I've a similar problem which only appears in newer versions of Chrome.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm experiencing the same problem, in a .net mvc web application. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, turns out that in my case this was the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624211/open-pdf-from-chrome-iframe-failed-with-default-pdf-viewer?rq=1
My link to the pdf was in a sandboxed iframe. If I remove the sandbox-attribute, the pdf opens correctly.

Comment: @ylva, Yes, that is what's going on, thank you. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by ylva, for anyone searching for this, the answer can be found here

[Open PDF from Chrome IFRAME failed with default PDF viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624211/open-pdf-from-chrome-iframe-failed-with-default-pdf-viewer?rq=1)

Main thing is, Chrome's PDF viewer embeds the PDF as an application, so if the link to a PDF file comes from an iframe, and this iframe has the sandbox attribute, chrome won't let it run, you either have to remove the sandbox attribute or have to install your own PDF viewer. So it had nothing to do with the PHP code itself.

Cheers

Comment: Would you care to expand on the "...install your own PDF viewer..." bit? Thanks.